# Is it possible order "Month Year" or "Year Month" in real date order using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, date, sql-order-by

I have a column "Date_Sold" from table in a format of "Mon DD YYYY"
I need to partial the month and year from "Date Sold" in a format of "Mon YYYY" or "YYYY Mon"

e.g. "Feb 2018" or "2018 Feb", 
I know how to partial them using

**"Select (left(Date_Sold, 3) + ' ' + Right(Date_Sold,4)) from Table"**

or **"Select (Right(Date_Sold,4) + ' ' + left(Date_Sold, 3)) from Table"**,

but the thing is, it cannot be ordered by real date in this format, it either in order

"2018 Apr" ->"2018 Aug"->"2018 Feb", 
or order "Apr 2018" -> "Dec 2017",

I also tried use

**"Select Convert(varchar(12), year([Date_Sold])) + ' ' + Convert(varchar(12), Month([Date_Sold])) from Table**"

to show year and month as "2018 10" format, 
but it also has issue that

October 2018 **"2018 10"** will come earlier than 
February 2018 **"2018 2"**

Is it possible to use SQL to show and order "Month Year" or "Year Month" in real date?

Comment: Why would you be storing a date as a string?

Comment: for work requirement, I need order "Mon Year" or "Year Mon" in real date as one dimension to show the historical trend

Comment: don't do it, oh don't do it! As you can see, you make everything more difficult.

Comment: 1. Change  `Convert(varchar(12), Month([Date_Sold]))` => `right('0'+Convert(varchar(12), Month([Date_Sold])),2)`

Comment: 2. `select convert(nvarchar(6),[Date_Sold],112)`

Comment: You can always `ORDER BY Date_Sold`, regardless of how your format the date in your select

Comment: `date`, `smalldatetime`, `datetime` and `datetime2` are **stored as numbers** then "translated" into a format for you to read. Using one of these data types is the ONLY way to correctly handle date/time information. Any attempt to use strings as dates/times will fail miserably, guaranteed. **STOP using strings**. FIX your data by using an appropriate data type. Then you will not have this avoidable problem.

Answer (score 0):

I offer you the following not as a reliable method to do what you ask, but as a way to convince you that storing date/time information as strings is just bad.

You need to "translate" the language dependent month names into integers (& note this would need to be done for any spoken language involved). Then you also need to locate the year, which I assume is the right 4 chars. Using `datefromparts()` you can arrive at a real/proper date to sort by (or you just use `order by y, m` but I wanted you to know how to get real dates too.)

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Date_Sold varchar(20)
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Date_Sold) VALUES ('Jan 17 2018');
INSERT INTO mytable(Date_Sold) VALUES ('Feb 14 2018');
INSERT INTO mytable(Date_Sold) VALUES ('Mar 13 2018');
INSERT INTO mytable(Date_Sold) VALUES ('Sep 10 2018');

select
*
from mytable
cross apply (
    select case
             when patindex('%jan%',date_sold) > 0 then 1 
             when patindex('%feb%',date_sold) > 0 then 2
             when patindex('%mar%',date_sold) > 0 then 3 
             when patindex('%apr%',date_sold) > 0 then 4 
             when patindex('%may%',date_sold) > 0 then 5 
             when patindex('%jun%',date_sold) > 0 then 6 
             when patindex('%jul%',date_sold) > 0 then 7 
             when patindex('%aug%',date_sold) > 0 then 8 
             when patindex('%sep%',date_sold) > 0 then 9 
             when patindex('%oct%',date_sold) > 0 then 10 
             when patindex('%nov%',date_sold) > 0 then 11 
             when patindex('%dec%',date_sold) > 0 then 12 
           end 
        , try_cast(right(date_sold,4) as integer)
    ) ca (m, y)
order by datefromparts(y,m,1)
```

Note that date sorting requires numbers. Handling dates/times requires a lot of number crunching (e.g. calculate "last month", "next week","this fiscal year" and a billion others). That is why `date`, `smalldatetime`, `datetime` and `datetime2` are **stored as numbers**.

Please do yourself a huge favour, don't store dates in MMM DD YYYY format.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact solution to your question. The problem is primarily that you save a date as a string (nvarchar) and not as a [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) datatype. You can do that, but it makes your life unnecessarily hard because you have to somehow rebuild all the functions that SQL has already implemented. Also, the database cannot ensure that the expected values are stored by the application. In a new version, the developer decides to use "12-12-2018" and not "Dec 12 2018", and then?

To avoid the trap of inaccuracy and uncertainty, the following approach is recommended.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactSales](
    [SalesOrderNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrderQuantity] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SalesAmount] [money] NOT NULL,
    [SalesDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FactSales] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SalesOrderNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FactSales]
           ([SalesOrderNumber]
           ,[ItemNumber]
           ,[OrderQuantity]
           ,[SalesAmount]
           ,[SalesDate])
     VALUES
           (1,1000,1,140.10,'2018-06-30 10:34:09'),
           (2,1005,10,40.10,'2018-07-30 1:34:09'),
           (3,1005,12,150.10,'2018-07-30 11:34:09'),
           (4,1009,3,199.10,'2018-08-30 11:34:09')
```

You store the sales date as DateTime. For further analysis, reporting or for the usage in your data warehouse, you can extract the month and year by using SQL functions:

```
SELECT *, datepart(month, SalesDate) as SalesMonth, datepart(year, SalesDate) as SalesYear From FactSales;
```